# Remove Image of ImageButton and set new Image

Tags: android, android-drawable, imagebutton

ImageButton's background is not getting changed
Everything is working counter is getting changed it was working till it was onTouchListener, I changed to onclickListener then changing of background stopped, how should I change background in onClickListener

I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/11835365/6648201 but it's not helping me

```
    final ImageButton user_btn_like = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.user_btn_like);

    user_btn_like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(presslikecount ==0) {
                user_btn_like.setPressed(true);
                presslikecount++;
                pressdislikecount = 0;

                user_btn_like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_user_like_red);
                user_btn_dislike.setPressed(false);
                user_btn_dislike.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_user_dislike_black);
                like.setText(String.valueOf(presslikecount));
                dislike.setText(String.valueOf(pressdislikecount));
            }
            else
                presslikecount--;
                user_btn_like.setPressed(false);
                user_btn_like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_user_like_black);
               like.setText(String.valueOf(presslikecount));
        }
    });
```

Comment: try using button.setImageResource();

Comment: user_btn_like is already has a image when activity started??

Comment: @ManishYadav yes I have set default Images to those imagebuttons

Comment: @Tony thanks man it worked

Comment: @Tony there is an issue, if I try to rechange the image it doesn't work

Comment: are you changing to a different image? this line of code that you changed is correct, if it's not working then you have another issue. EDIT: if it works the first  time but not the second time then your code has a logical error and not a syntax

Comment: @Tony when I add code to change Image 2nd time even first image change code doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 user_btn_like.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_user_like_red);
```

Instead of

```
 user_btn_like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_user_like_red);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        > user_btn_like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        > 
        > boolean clicked = false;
        > 
        >         @Override
        >         public void onClick(View view) {
        >             if(!clicked) {
        >                //user liked it
        >                clicked = true
                         user_btn_like.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_user_like_red);
                          like.settext("1");
        >             }
        >             else
        >                 {
        >                   clicked = false;
                               // user disliked it`enter code here`
        >                     
        >                     }
        >         }
        >     });
```

Comment: image is not getting changed